# Laravel Vue How to update a column in the user table from Vue

Tags: php, laravel, api, vue.js, vuex

I want to send a request to Laravel from Vue to update a column for the currently logged in User.

So far I have setup Vuex, where I am sending a a post request with axios. however I keep getting an error 419. which apparently means its a CSRF token problem.

1. How would I parse the CSRF token to my backend the current method in my code does not work.
2. is there a alternative route that would be easier.

Route in api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::post('prequalify', 'OfferController@update');
});
```

controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;

class OfferController extends Controller
{
    function update(Request $request){
        $user = Auth::user();
        return $user;
        //Send Request to Majestic and get a response
        $response = true;
            if($response){
                $user->is_qualified = true;
            }else{
                $user->is_qualified = false;
            }

            $user->save();


        return $request;
    }
}
```

Vue Method
and I am able to get the CSRF token.

```
preQualify(){
        let csrf= document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
        this.$store.dispatch('prequalify',{csrf});
    }
```

VUEX actions

```
import axios from 'axios';
let actions = {
    prequalify({commit,state}, payload){
        axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = payload.csrf;
        axios.post('/api/prequalify',state.LoanCalculator)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            })
    }
}
export default actions
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `api.php` you are using `web` middleware which checks for `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware that middleware responsibility to verify `CSRF` tokens and that what gives you the `419`, to make it simpler you need to remove `web` middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => []], function () {
    Route::post('prequalify', 'OfferController@update');
});
```

in this case there is no need for sending `X-CSRF-TOKEN` in your `axios` call.

**Note** - if `prequalify` endpoint requires that user should be authenticated you need to use the right middleware corresponding to `auth` system you are using which could `passport` or `sanctum`.

Answer (score 0):

i used like this

in `bootstrap.js`

```js
window.csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content");
```

then in axios `req.`

```js
 axios.post('/api/prequalify',{_token:csrfToken,data:state.LoanCalculator})
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            })
```

may be there is any better way but i used this in my application hope it can solve your issue

Comment: what middleware is being used in `/api/prequalify` here .?